# How to skip the function with lambda code inside?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2010

Consider the fragment below:

```
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    private A GetA(string b)
    {
        return this.aCollection.FirstOrDefault(a => a.b == b);
    }
```

If I use F11 debugger doesn't skip the function instead it stops at **a.b == b**.

Is there any way to jump over this function rather than using F10?

Comment: When does it stop there?   Are you clicking step in an it steps in to the beginning of the function GetA()?   Is there a breakpoint?  what do you mean it stops at "a.b == b"?

Comment: Normally you would use F10 to step over a function.  Why don't you want to use F10 in this instance?

Comment: Normally you would use F11 during the debugging without any thinking about what key combination to use F11 or F10. DebuggerStepThrough helps a lot but not always.

Comment: Are you sure you are not experiencing a first chance exception on the `a => a.b == b`?

Comment: I figured it out! -- You can't do it with Lambdas, but you *can* do it with Expression Trees which give you a very similar syntax with a few limitations -- see my answer below!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see why it happens but don't have a way to get around it. Perhaps someone can build on this. The lambda expression gets compiled into an Anonymous Method.

I see: Program.GetA.AnonymousMethod__0(Test a)

Just like if you called another method in the method you've shown, pressing F11 would go into that method. eg/

```
[DebuggerStepThrough]
static A GetA<A>(IList<A> aCollection, string b) where A : Test
{
    DoNoOp();
    return aCollection.FirstOrDefault(a => a.b == b);
}

static void DoNoOp()
{
    // noop
    Console.WriteLine("got here");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for the answer. I understand too why it happens, because lambda is just a shortcut for another function. I've asked with the hope maybe I'm missing something new in the VS2010. It seems that debugger of VS2010 might be improved a bit by extending the option to "Step over properties and operators (Managed only)." with lambda expressions.

Comment: I agree with y'all that this seems to be a major limitation -- in the meantime, I've provided a pseudo-workaround in my answer below which gives the desired results at a slight limitation, and potential performance penalty...  Take a look and let me know what you think!

Answer (score 4):

IMO this is a bug in the C# compiler. The compiler should also place those attributes on the anonymous methods. The workaround is to fallback to doing the work manually that the C# compiler does for you:

```
[DebuggerStepThrough]
private A GetA(string b)
{
    var helper = new Helper { B = b };

    return this.aCollection.FirstOrDefault(helper.AreBsEqual);
}

private class Helper
{
    public string B;

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool AreBsEqual(A a) { return a.b == this.B; }
}
```

But of course this is nasty and quite unreadable. That's why the C# compiler should have done this. But the difficult question for the C# team is of course: which of the attributes that you place on a method must be copied to internal anonymous methods and which should not?

Comment: I disagree that this is a bug. Anonymous methods aren't always simple expressions; they can be long and complex. I'd not want the compiler arbitrarily skipping any anonymous method or lambda.

Comment: @DanPuzey: I do agree that the compiler shouldn't simply skip any anonymous method or lambda, but it IMO it should when the containing method itself is decorated with that attribute, since that's what the attribute is for.

Comment: Ah, I see - sorry, I'd missed the distinction. My mistake!

Comment: @DanPuzey if anonymous methods are long and complex, that is probably an extremely good reason to pull them out into regular methods.

Answer (score 0):

This bothered me for a long time, today I figured out a way to do it using Expression trees in .NET 4.0.

Consider the following code:

```
private class Borked
{
    public object X 
    {
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}

private void SomeMethod()
{
    var bad = new Borked();
    object obj = bad.TryGet(o => o.X);
}
```

Now -- I'm able to call this code without missing a beat -- the only place the debugger would try to stop is in Borked's broken getter property -- so that's why I added the `DebuggerStepThrough` attribute there.

Instead of taking in a lambda, I take in an expression tree (which uses the same syntax!!), and I compile and run it at runtime -- it's a *little* more work (barely) than using a regular lambda, and it won't work for everything, but for simple Linq queries and such, it works great.

All the magic happens in the following method -- which, again, originally used to accept a regular `Func<>` argument -- but that paused the debugger when an exception was thrown (despite the step-through attribute), so now I do it with an `Expression<Func<>>` like so:

```
[DebuggerStepThrough]
public static T TryGet<OT, T>(this OT obj, params Expression<Func<OT, T>>[] getters)
{
    T ret = default(T);

    if (getters != null)
    {
        foreach (var getter in getters)
        {
            try
            {
                if (getter != null)
                {
                    var getter2 = (Func<OT, T>)getter.Compile();
                    ret = getter2(obj);
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch
            { /* try next getter or return default */ }
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

That's right -- you just call `.Compile()` and cast the return value to a regular `Func<>` that you can immediately invoke!! -- How easy was that?!

In my implementation, I let the user pass in multiple parameters so that they have a way to get a fallback value (and that that fallback value is only created/evaluated *IF* required).

Also, I'm not sure if the reason the Debug event is being suppressed is because of VisualStudio's "Just my Code", or because it's being run inline in this method..., but either way it freakin' works, dang it!!

Now, I'm guessing that calling that `.Compile` method on the expression at run-time isn't super fast, but, in practice, it doesn't seem to be adding any performance penalty for me in my queries.  So, I'm pretty excited (please excuse the multiple/redundant bangs and interobangs, etc.)

Comment: Why the downvote? -- this works for getters (which the OP was trying to do) -- It doesn't work for setters or things with side effects -- but it's still the only solution so far that comes close to addressing the issue. (My hopes for the future is that someone will submit a patch to the Roslyn compiler for this.)